# Encrypt something on a server without decryption key available

Tags: encryption

say you have some string:

```
bank_account = '12345';
```

and you want to encrypt it automatically with some method:

```
magic_encrypt(bank_account);
```

and store it. The decryption password/code will not exist on the server, and so the server needs to be able to encrypt it the data without being able to decrypt it. This way if the server is compromised, none of the stored data would be able to be decrypted by an evil 3rd party.

The data, when needed, would be pulled from the server and decrypted in a secure environment.

What type of encryption should I use?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called asymmetric key cryptography. Algorithms like [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) and [ElGamal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption) will do that.